# Docker: Unable to view running container despite successful demo example

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, docker, dockerfile

When I run the example from the [Docker doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/usingdocker/) in the "Viewing our web application container" section, i.e.,

`docker run -d -P training/webapp python app.py`

...I'm able to view the "Hello World" output in a browser. Success. This seems to indicate that the network I'm on may not be the problem.

Now I'm trying to view a container that runs a webdriver suite (test automation of a browser). Based on the output in docker logs -f, the webdriver suite runs to completion. But when I try to point a browser at the webdriver container (which is running the browser), I get a error saying:

`ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Here are the steps I'm following:

1. Start webdriver container with this command
   `docker run -d -p 8080:5000 "/bin/bash" "-c" "/dir1/dir2/filename.sh $PARAMETER1 $PARAMETER2"`
2. point a browser to:
   `http://subdomain.mydomain.com:5000`

Docker output:

```
user@server$ docker ps -l  
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
2fa83fc0401a        65525ab9ad78        "/bin/bash -c '/opt/y"   55 minutes ago      Up 55 minutes       2222/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->5000/tcp  

user@server$ docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' 2fa83fc0401a  
111.22.33.4444
```

Other info:
Server config: Ubuntu 14.04
Docker version: 1.8.1, build d12ea79

I've reviewed the following questions but I'm not running on a VM and I'm not running NodeJS.
[Unable to view rails app running in docker container from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33190617/unable-to-view-rails-app-running-in-docker-container-from-browser)
[Docker: Unable to specify port for a running container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28510562/docker-unable-to-specify-port-for-a-running-container)

Does anyone have suggestions on how I might troubleshoot this problem? Any assistance gratefully accepted.

:) jay

Update 1:
Based on the NodeJS question noted above, I'm thinking that I'm not setting a port correctly in the Dockerfile. Maybe this is as simple as setting the correct port for Selenium?

Update 2: as @hunter noted, I had the ports in the wrong order, but switching the ports does not resolve the problem. I think the bigger problem is that I was assigning the wrong port. So, I changed `docker run -d -p 8080:5000` to `docker run -d -P`. When I did that, I got the following output:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                              COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    
f375251b61d7        65525ab9ad78                       "/bin/bash -c '/opt/y"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:33073->2222/tcp
```

I then pointed the browser to that port: `http://subdomain.mydomain.com:33073`

But I still get the same error: `ERR CONNECTION REFUSED`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using the wrong port - the external port is 8080 not 5000.

Comment: many thanks for your response. You are correct about the wrong port, although unfortunately that did not solve this problem. See update 2 for details.